Is there a way to find the amount of integer outputs for a function?
Given a function f, is there a simple method to find the amount of possible inputs x that output an integer f(x)?

The set of ouputs of a function is the range or image of the function.  If the function is continuous, then the range will be some interval and we can count the number of integers in that interval.  But, it is possible that the range is not simple to find.
